# What happened when Application terminate while Thread pool not yet finished?

Tags: winapi

I'm new to Thread pool API. I'm confusing with `CloseThreadpool`. It's say:

`The thread pool is closed immediately if there are no outstanding work, I/O, timer, or wait objects that are bound to the pool; otherwise, the thread pool is released asynchronously after the outstanding objects are freed.`

If I call `CloseThreadpool` and immediately return from `main` or `WinMain` while there is pending work, I/O, timer or wait objects. What will happen with pending operations? Is it discarded?

Comment: Your CRT's _exit() function will call TerminateProcess().  Kaboom, over.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there anyway to wait all pending operations to complete? I have searched and found `WaitForThreadpoolXXXCallbacks`. But, it is used to wait a single pending operation.

Comment: Fire-and-forget threading is very convenient.  Until you discover that you can't really forget of course.  You'll have to interlock this yourself.  A semphore gets the job done.

Comment: @HansPassant I know when you come, all WinAPI problems will be solved. Thanks you very much!